# Get required state for input

Tags: angularjs

This code in [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qurabazuxa/edit?html,js,output) :

I want to hide or show the asterisk when the input email is required using AngularJS model

Already checked these ones:

- email.$validators.required
- email.required
- email.ngRequired
- email.ngRequired()

Html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <form ng-controller="controllerUser">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="rt-grid-2 label-form">
                <span class="required">*</span>
                <span>User Type</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="userType" name="userType" ng-model="userType" ng-required="true">
                    <option value=''>select</option>
                    <option value='personal'>Personal</option>
                    <option value='company'>Company</option>
                </select>
                <div class="errorMessage"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="rt-grid-2 label-form">
                <span class="required" ng-hide="email.required">*</span>
                <span>E-mail</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-maxlength="50" ng-required="isCompany()">
                <div class="errorMessage"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('controllerUser', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isCompany = function () {
    return $scope.userType == 'company';
  };
}]);
```

I try different forms but isn't working.

Comment: Please include your angularJS code in your question as well.  Your JSFiddle has no Javascript code either.

Comment: ng-required is set to true. So the email is always required. So you don't need ng-hide.

Comment: No , I not have, I want to know if is possible do it only with expression <span class="required" ng-hide="**Here**">*</span>

Comment: This is an only field of my form, but the others inputs have conditions for required, then I want show or hide the asterisk depending the state of model

Comment: Clarify what you want. It's not clear. Your email field is always required. So I don't see what ng-hide is for. Or maybe you want to show the asterisk if the email field is **blank**, i.e. if the required validation **fails**?